# Confusing (x, y) origins with sub-views in interface builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ipad

I have a view in interface builder, and then a subview within that view.  I place the sub-view visually near the upper left corner within its parent.  I would therefore expect the x, y coordinates of the sub-views frame to be something close to (20,20), but instead IB tells me it is something like (230,432).  If I then adjust the X, Y coords in the properties window to something like (20,20), the sub-view flies off the screen towards the upper-left...  What is the deal?  BTW, it is an iPad specific view size, where the top/parent view is sized 768x1004.

Answer (score 9):

In the Size & Position section, in the grid on the left, make sure the top-left corner dot is selected.  The dot selected in this grid determines what the X and Y coordinates refer to.

You may have the center dot selected and so the X,Y coordinates indicate the coordinates of the sub-view's center relative to the parent.

[image]

Comment: Does this "Origin" setting have any runtime representation or is this only design time helper feature of Interface builder?

Comment: The top-left dot corresponds to a UIView's frame.origin and the center dot to a UIView's center property.  The rest are just for design-time convenience.

Comment: This was driving me crazy why my frame.origin.y movements were not taking effect as expected. I had the UIImageview center dot checked.
Thank you!!